# Delete bot's messages from member's DM when members leave the server

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to delete the messages that my bot has sent to any user, when they leave the server. Following is the code that I have tried but seems that it doesn't do anything... Can someone correct the code if they can help?

```
@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member, message):
    #delete messages from dm
    messages_to_remove = 10
    async for message in client.get_user(member).history(limit=messages_to_remove):
      if message.author.id == client.member.id:
        await message.delete()
```

Comment: I can't delete the messages that user has sent, however I am entirely sure that I can delete messages that my bot has sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already said, you can only delete the messages of the bot.

There is no direct method to get the private messages, so we have to build our own function.

**Have a look at the following code:**

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    dmchannel = await member.create_dm() # "Create" a DM
    async for message in dmchannel.history(limit=10): # Async through the messages
        if message.author == client.user: # Check that the author is the bot
            await message.delete() # Delete 10 messages if possible
```

Comment: that's exactly what I wanted, worked thank you